# im trying to store likes in localstorage but its not working for me

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, state

As explained, I am using localstorage to save my cart as well as previously liked photos. It works fine for cart items but it is not saving updates to the 'liked' photos. What am i doing wrong here?

I have tried a number of things including splitting out the useffects and managing the dependancy array for them but to no avail. When i check the application tag it is successfully updating the isfavorite value for the individual photo but once refreshing it goes back to the default.

```
import React,{ useState,useEffect } from "react";
const Context = React.createContext()

function ContextProvider(props){
    const [allPhotos, setAllPhotos] = useState([])
    const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([])
    const url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bobziroll/scrimba-react-bootcamp-images/master/images.json"
    useEffect(() => {
      fetch(url)
      .then(res=>res.json())
      .then(data => setAllPhotos(data))
    }, [])


    const toggleFavorites = (id) =>{
        const updatedArray = allPhotos.map(photo=> {
            if (photo.id === id){
                return {...photo, isFavorite: !photo.isFavorite}
            } return photo
        })
        setAllPhotos(updatedArray)
    }

    const addItem = (newItem) => {
        setCartItems(prevItems=>([...prevItems,newItem]))
    }

    const removeItem = (id) => {
        setCartItems(prevItems=>(prevItems.filter(item=>item.id !== id)))
    }

    function emptyCart(){
        setCartItems([])
    }

    useEffect(()=> {
        const cartData = window.localStorage.getItem("CART_SETTINGS")
        if (cartData !== null) setCartItems(JSON.parse(cartData))
    },[])

    useEffect(()=> {
        const photoData = window.localStorage.getItem("PHOTO_SETTINGS")
        if (photoData !== null) setAllPhotos(JSON.parse(photoData))
    },[])


    useEffect(()=> {
        window.localStorage.setItem(`PHOTO_SETTINGS`, JSON.stringify(allPhotos))
        window.localStorage.setItem(`CART_SETTINGS`, JSON.stringify(cartItems))
    },[allPhotos, cartItems])

    
    return (
        <Context.Provider value={{
            allPhotos, 
        toggleFavorites,
        cartItems, 
        addItem,
        removeItem, 
        emptyCart}}>
            {props.children}
        </Context.Provider>
    )
}

export {ContextProvider, Context}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're saving your allPhotos state to local storage only once when the component is mounted. Then, you're setting allPhotos from the data you get from the fetch request. But, you're not updating local storage when you toggle favorites.

This is because the useEffect hook that saves the allPhotos and cartItems to local storage only runs on the initial render and when allPhotos and cartItems change. But, you're updating allPhotos with setAllPhotos inside toggleFavorites after the initial render, and you're not saving this updated state to local storage.

Here's how you can modify toggleFavorites to save the allPhotos state to local storage after you've toggled a favorite:

```
const toggleFavorites = (id) => {
    const updatedArray = allPhotos.map(photo => {
        if (photo.id === id){
            return {...photo, isFavorite: !photo.isFavorite}
        } 
        return photo
    })
    setAllPhotos(updatedArray)

    // Save to local storage
    window.localStorage.setItem(`PHOTO_SETTINGS`, JSON.stringify(updatedArray))
}
```

Now, the updated allPhotos state will be saved to local storage whenever you toggle a favorite, and it will persist across page reloads.

Note: Consider handling potential exceptions for operations related to localStorage for better user experience and data reliability. The browser may restrict its usage (for instance in incognito mode in some browsers, or when it's disabled manually), and localStorage operations may throw errors.

Comment: thanks a lot that worked, I thought about your above logic and it makes perfect sense now. I also realised i wasn't making allPhotos a dependancy when getting the items. Will add error handlers to finalise this